In VBA, I want to reply to an email simulating exactly as if the user hit "reply all", but signature image becomes error
I have the following code. My objective is to basically create a replier in VBA that simulates exactly what would happen if user clicked "Reply all" on outlook. It works almost perfectly but I the images from the signatures become errors in the reply email. Here's the code:
Sub LookForEmail(EmailSubject As String)

    Dim objNS As outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olFolder As outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem
    Dim MailFolder As outlook.Items
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim Counter As Integer
    
    sFilter = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" like '%" & EmailSubject & "%'"
    Set MailFolder = olFolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
    MailFolder.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
    
    For Each Item In MailFolder
        If TypeOf Item Is outlook.MailItem Then
            Dim oMail As outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
            If oMail.Subject = EmailSubject Then
                
                Set NewMail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

                With NewMail
                    .Display
                    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body><span>test</span><Body></HTML>" _
                    & "<span>" & "test2" & "</span>" _
                    & oMail.ReplyAll.HTMLBody
                    .To = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
                    .cc = oMail.cc
                    .BCC = oMail.BCC
                    .Subject = oMail.Subject 'add here the code
                    .Display
                End With
                
                Exit For
                
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    
End Sub

I'm guessing it's a problem with the HTML format but I'm not much of an expert on that. Thank you in advance.
I tried creating a new email object in order to include all the details I wanted to but the siganure is still off.

No need to simulate: there is a method for this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyall(method)

Thank you. I'm infact using that method. I'm trying to "type" in the body of the email as if the user had clicked on "reply all"

I missed that, but why not just directly work with the mail object returned by the ReplyAll method?  I'm guessing that may also have any embedded signature images attached to it...

You cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML, the two must be merged. Read the existing HTMLBody property, find the position of the <body> tag, and insert your HTML immediately after that tag.

You may prefix your text to the standard Item.replyall.
Option Explicit

Sub LookForEmail(emailSubject As String)
   
    Dim olFolder As folder
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Dim mailFolderItems As Items
    Dim Item As Object
    
    Dim replyMail As MailItem
    
    Dim sFilter As String
    
    sFilter = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" like '%" & emailSubject & "%'"
    
    Set mailFolderItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
    mailFolderItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
    
    For Each Item In mailFolderItems
    
        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
            
            If Item.Subject = emailSubject Then
                
                Set replyMail = Item.replyall

                With replyMail
                
                    .Display    ' initial .htmlbody and default signature
                    
                    ' add to the initial .htmlbody
                    .htmlbody = "<HTML><Body><span>test</span><Body></HTML>" _
                      & "<span>" & "test2" & "</span>" _
                      & .htmlbody
                      
                End With
                
                Exit For
                
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

